# For loop does not work when web scraping multiple URLs. Only scrapes one URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape multiple websites for different types of products. I was able to web scrape one url. I created a list to web scrape multiple urls, then export the product name and price to a CVL file. However, it does not appear to be working as needed.

Below is my code:

```
#imports
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Product Websites For Consolidation
urls = ['https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/stripped-lowers?product_list_limit=all', 'https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/complete-lowers?product_list_limit=all']
for url in urls:
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


    #Locating All Products On Page
    all_products_on_page = soup.find(class_='products wrapper container grid products-grid')
    individual_items = all_products_on_page.find_all(class_='product-item-info')


    #Breaking Down Product By Name And Price
    aero_product_name = [item.find(class_='product-item-link').text for item in individual_items]
    aero_product_price = [p.text if (p := item.find(class_='price')) is not None else 'no price' for item in individual_items]


    Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Aero Product': aero_product_name,
        'Prices': aero_product_price,
        })

    Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated.to_csv('MasterPriceTracker.csv')
```

The code exports the product name and price as desired to a CVL file, but only for the second URL, the "complete-lowers" one. I'm not sure what I'm messing up in the For loop to cause it not to web scrape both URLs. I verified the HTML code is the same for both URLs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's `if (p := item.find(class_='price'))`? I've never seen `:=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `to_csv` call outside the loop. Because it was inside the loop, it was rewriting the csv file for each entry (hence only the last entry showed up in the file).

Within the loop, append the dictionaries to the dataframe created before the loop starts. Also, there is no need for the `headers` to be redefined each time in the loop, so I pulled them outside too.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Product Websites For Consolidation
urls = ['https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/stripped-lowers?product_list_limit=all', 'https://www.aeroprecisionusa.com/ar15/lower-receivers/complete-lowers?product_list_limit=all']

Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Aero Product', 'Prices'])
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"}

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


    #Locating All Products On Page
    all_products_on_page = soup.find(class_='products wrapper container grid products-grid')
    individual_items = all_products_on_page.find_all(class_='product-item-info')


    #Breaking Down Product By Name And Price
    aero_product_name = [item.find(class_='product-item-link').text for item in individual_items]
    aero_product_price = [p.text if (p := item.find(class_='price')) is not None else 'no price' for item in individual_items]


    Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated = Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated.append(pd.DataFrame(
        {'Aero Product': aero_product_name,
        'Prices': aero_product_price,
        }))

Aero_Stripped_Lowers_Consolidated.to_csv('MasterPriceTracker.csv')
```

Comment: I made the changes you made, even copied and pasted the exact code. It gives me the error "TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name"

Comment: I made the changes you made, even copied and pasted the exact code. It gives me the error "TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name" @Sam Chats

Comment: I think there was slight error in the code. I edited it. try it again

Comment: @chitown88 Thanks, I missed it! I should've tested it before submitting.

Comment: @SamChats, I knew what you meant though, but someone new wouldn't have caught it. BTW, what's `p :=` part? I've never seen that. Gives me a syntax error

Comment: @SamChats  It definitely works now after the edit. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @chitown88 It's the walrus operator, available from Python 3.8. It gives a syntax error perhaps because your Python version is <3.8. See https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/

Comment: Yup. I’m on python 3.7. Thanks for filling me in.